# Run prettier on ts and scss files

Tags: typescript, sass, prettier

I am trying to configurate my prettier for typescript and scss files

I have have the following .pretterrc file:

```
{
    "printWidth": 100,
    "parser": "typescript",
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "arrowParens": "avoid"
}
```

When running my prettier it errors on the scss files:

```
SyntaxError: Expression expected. (1:2)
[error] > 1 | @import
```

When I change the parser to `"parser": "scss"` then prettier errors on my ts files.

How can I run Prettier on all my files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `parser` option.

If you use VSCode, you need to install the extension.

Prettier will automatically detect which language you are using.